# Extracting data from a radar chart in a scanned document

Tags: python, opencv, radar-chart

I would like to convert this radar graph into numeric values for each component (dotted lines), using openCV for python. How would I best do this? I've been thinking about detecting the center of the graph as well as the intersections of the dotted lines with the gray area. By doing this I could measure the distance between the center and each of these intersections to determine a value for each component. However this seems rather complex, and I have no idea how to start. Could someone help me out here?

EDIT: The purpose is to write a piece of software that can extract data from 250 of these graphs. (I have better quality scans)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (sorry it's pseudo-code, if you think the idea it's good enough I'll try to write some real code):

1.find the circle center(maybe using HoughCircle function)

2.inverse thresholding to highlight your dark grey area

3.Call opencv function approx poly to get the polygon representing this area

4.for each vertex, measure its distance from the center and convert it to your desidered scale

I think it should work.

hough circle tutorial
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

approx poly tutorial
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

**EDIT**:

I've had some spare time so I wrote an initial piece of code to extract  circle, radius and the poly, hope it helps you

```
    img = cv.imread("c:\\temp\\test.jpg", cv.IMREAD_COLOR) 
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #thresholds for isolate circle and poly
    ret, thres_poly_temp = cv.threshold(gray, 90, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    ret, thres_circle = cv.threshold(gray, 110, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    #cleanup image for detect poly
    thres_poly = thres_poly_temp.copy()
    thres_poly = cv.GaussianBlur(thres_poly_temp,(3,3),0)
    thres_poly = cv.medianBlur( thres_poly, 5)

    #bitwise_and to keep just the poly, removing the circle 
    cv.bitwise_and(thres_poly_temp, thres_circle, thres_poly)
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3),np.uint8)
    thres_poly  = cv.morphologyEx(thres_poly, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3),np.uint8)
    thres_poly  = cv.morphologyEx(thres_poly, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    #find circle
    circle = cv.HoughCircles(thres_circle, 3, 2, 800, minRadius = 100, maxRadius=500, param1=80, param2=100)
    radius_list = []
    if circle is not None:
        circle = np.round(circle[0, :]).astype("int")
        for (x,y,r) in circle:
            cv.circle(gray, (x,y), r, (255,255,0),3)
            cv.circle(gray, (x,y), 3, (255,255,0),3)
            radius_list.append((x+r,y))
            a = 0
            #find radius
            while(a < 360):
                rad = math.radians(a)
                x2 = int((radius_list[0][0] - x) * math.cos(rad)) - int((radius_list[0][1] - y) * math.sin(rad)) + x;
                y2 = int((radius_list[0][0] - x) * math.sin(rad)) + int((radius_list[0][1] - y) * math.cos(rad)) + y;
                radius_list.append((x2,y2))
                a = a + 18
                cv.line(gray, (x,y), (x2,y2), (255,255,0),2)

    #find poly contour
    contours,hierarchy = cv.findContours(thres_poly, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    #extract contour with max area
    maxArea = -1
    maxAreaContour = contours[0]
    for contour in contours:
        area = abs(cv.contourArea(contour))
        if area > maxArea:
            maxArea = area
            maxAreaContour = contour

    #approx poly to get contours
    epsilon = 0.1*cv.arcLength(maxAreaContour,True)
    approx = cv.approxPolyDP(maxAreaContour, 5, True)
    cv.drawContours(gray, [approx],-1,(0,255,0),2)
    cv.imshow("1", gray)

    #now just iterate all the radius with the contour to find the intersection
    # it should be pretty straight forward
```

[output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGP1F.png)

**EDIT 2**: still missing: align image, as I said you can use the horizontal and vertical dotted lines to do that (use hough lines to get them,then determine m and q and do the inverse roto-translation)

Comment: Problem is that it might not find vertices, if the grey are keeps going straight. For example look at the green "HOP" area. There are 3 components there for which the value is more or less the same, so there is no angle on the middle line. Also when looking at the brown "WILDE FLORA" segment, we can see that there isn't any grey area there, so no vertices would be detected here as well...

Comment: You're right, I didn't noticed that...What do you think about finding intersection between the polygon you've just found at point 3 and the circle radius to determine the value?

Comment: You can use the the dotted lines on the top left to align your image, then you know there is one radius every 18 degrees (5 per quarter), so you do the math and find all the radius coordinates, then you check their intersections with your poly